# Replace word update, insert and delete from string in jquery

Tags: jquery

Just wandering how can I replace word update, insert and delete from string in jquery?

I'm using the following script to do it, just wandering do there have any better way instead of this?

```
string a = "Update the person, update then delete the person, insert the message"; 
a.toUpper().replace("UPDATE", "").replace("DELETE","").replace("INSERT", "");
```

OUTPUT: the person, then the person, the message

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex. Match UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT followed by optional white space, g means global to replace all instances, not just the first and i is case insensitive.

```js
let a = "Update the person, update then delete the person, insert the message"; 
console.log(a.replace(/(UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT)\s?/gi, ""));
```